# Automation for a login on a program on startup of Windows

Tags: batch, script, login, automation, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a program that works as a network-server for a 2nd program which does connect to the manufacturer-server of the autoparts using the 1st one. Retail workers uses the 2nd program to check prices then. Problem is that the network-server program needs to log in with given credentials by the developer, this task of login is needed everyday because the machine where it is installed is restarted at midnight by a backup program that saves the logs of transactions done on the day, gets the backup file done then restarts the machine to finish cleaning temporal files. If 1st program isnt up the workers cant make any request of a product price with 2nd one so I need to automate the login onto the network program daily. It is already on Windows startup and it doesnt have remember login option so atm Im lacking the automation of introducing credentials daily just one time.

Comment: Either the software supports automatic login, or you use some automation tool to do this. Frankly, I'd start asking the software Dev why their software requires an active user session to operate, because servers are generally designed to run without direct interaction.

Comment: Google: "AutoIt"

Comment: @Gantendo U got it right, just what I needed. Thank you. Gonna make use of it.